# No me funciona un atajo de teclado en visual studio code

Tags: html5, vscode

Cuándo voy a escribir un archivo .html, normalmente presiono la tecla Mayús+1 (que me da !) para que se me dé la opción de que se autocomplete la estrucutra básica de un html.
Hace unas horas que lo desinstalé, volví a instalar ya me funcionaba dicho atajo.
Horas más tarde ya no me aparece dicha opción.

Nota: soy todo un novato en visual studio code, por ende es probable que lo que intenté haber hecho para solucionarlo antes fuera un intento estupido pero pues bueno.

Vi en otras páginas web que tenía que hacer esto:
En Visual Studio Code: Archivo> Preferencias> Configuración> Extensiones> Emmet> Editar en el
archivo settings.json

Agregue el siguiente código que funcionó para mí.

"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"files.associations": {"*html":"html"},
Lo que yo hice fúe solo copiar las líneas en dicha parte que originalmente estaban así:

```
  {
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "%DIR%/build",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "emmet.preferences": {
    
    }
  }
```

Después de mi intento quedó así:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "%DIR%/build",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "emmet.preferences": {
    
    }
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"files.associations": {"*html":"html"}
}
```

Obviamente no funciono.
Nota: todos los demás atajos si funcionan, escribo por ejemplo h para poner un h1 y si me aparece la opción de autocompletado.

Comment: ME pasa exactamente lo mismo, pudiste solucionarlo??